# Viewing Python's shelve objects in PHP

Tags: php, python, shelve

I am using Python for indexing utilizing the [shelve](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/shelve.html) functionality and I was wondering whether it was possible to open and read the files in PHP.

I checked out the PHP Shelve option and it doesn't seem to be working on PHP 5.X I am getting (when running the example they gave me)

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in test.php on line 205

Even still, I don't think I'd get the same performance writing to the shelve in PHP as I would in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how mature or well developed that project is, but, if I had that need, I would try the [Python In PHP](http://www.csh.rit.edu/~jon/projects/pip/) project.